# Numpy: finding the indices of the 2 numbers in an array that is closest to input

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large array with values from 0 to 360 in increments of .08. So I have an input value and I need to go through this large array and find the 2 closest values: the one that is greater and the one that is less. For example (simplified):

```
array = [0, .08, .16, .24, .32, .40]

input = .10 (variable)
output = [1,2]
```

since .10 is in between .08 and .16 the indices will be 1 and 2. 
Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Is it a simplified example or the actual problem? `[int(0.10/0.08), int(0.10/0.08)+1]` would do...

Comment: Yea that's a simplified example. The array is about 4500 long and the input will be variable.

Comment: The solution is valid even with a variable input as long as the step is constant.

Comment: I see, it does work indeed! What if I wanted to do this for an array in which the step isn't constant? I have another array with latitude and the step changes depending on earth's radius?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your step isn't constant, you can use `bisect` assuming you array is sorted.

```
import bisect

array = [0, .03, .05, .16, .24, .32, .40]
input = 0.1
ind = bisect.bisect_left(array, input)
print([ind - 1, ind])
```

Results:

```
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like numpy has the function nailed:
[searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html#numpy.searchsorted)

```
array = [0, .03, .05, .16, .24, .32, .40]
input = 0.1
undx = np.searchsorted(array, input)

array[undx-1], input, array[undx]
Out[6]: (0.05, 0.1, 0.16)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a arithmetic problem with O(1) solution :

```
a=arange(0,360,0.08)
input=123.456

i=int(input/0.08)

print(a[i:i+2])
print([i,i+1])
#[ 123.44  123.52]
#[1543, 1544]
```